# How to fix LGHT0242 Invalid Product Version error in Wix

Tags: wix

Using Wix 3.11

I am trying to include a third-party msi file in my Wix bundle and it gives me this error:

`error LGHT0242: Invalid product version '4' in package '<package name>'. When included in a bundle, all product version fields in an MSI package must be less than 65536.`

I am not sure how to proceed because by the error message -- the value appears to be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProductVersion` [must be](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/productversion) in the format `major.minor.build`. '4' does not match this format that's why you got this error.

You may [inspect](https://4sysops.com/archives/edit-an-msi-file-with-the-orca-msi-editor/) msi's product version using [Orca](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/orca-exe) tool.

You can use [wirunsql.vbs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-scripting-examples) to [change](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c8fdb871-4c7b-4a81-8342-a5ef5b2eb2b2/productversion-format?forum=winformssetup) `ProductVersion` in the msi:

```
C:\cscript "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17134.0\x64\wirunsql.vbs" "C:\Projects\SomeProject.msi" "UPDATE `Property` SET `Property`.`Value` ='2.3.4.5' WHERE `Property`.`Property` ='ProductVersion'"
```

Found this thread with explanation of version properties in msi: [msi version numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312221/msi-version-numbers).

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I thought about trying that but I read the error message as saying it needed to be a short number. I see now it is talking about the individual parts of the version. Thanks!